# как что то добавить в список json через python

Tags: python, json

Я пытаюсь вот в такой json файл добавить третьего пользователя
{"login": ["@user", "@user2"], "password": ["user", "user2"]}

вот таким кодом но у меня ничего не выходит, как мне добавить нового пользователя в список и чтобы эти изменения были видны в самом json файле

```
import json

with open(r"C:\Users\young\Desktop\auto-bot-vidri\data\data.json") as data:
    data_file = json.load(data)

data_file["login"].append("@user")

with open(r"C:\Users\young\Desktop\auto-bot-vidri\data\data.json", "w") as newdata:
    json.dump(data_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

У словаря нет метода `append`

Вот так

```py
data_file["login"] = "@user"
```